# Non-Linear Differential Equation Change of Variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

> The function $v(x,t)$ satisfies:
>   $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2} + \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2$$
>   for $0<x<1$, the initial condition $v(x,0) = 0$ for $0\le x\le1$, and the boundary conditions
>   $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 1\,\,\,\text{ at }\,\,\,x=0,\,t>0\,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,v=0\,\,\,\text{ at }\,\,\,x=1,\,t>0$$
>   By change of dependent variable defined by $v=\ln u$, $u\ne0$, transforms the problem to:
>   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$
>   for $0<x<1$ where $u(x,t)$ satisfies the conditions $u(x,0) = 1$ for $0\le x\le1$ and
>   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = u\,\,\,\text{ at }\,\,\,x=0,\,t>0\,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,u=1\,\,\,\text{ at }\,\,\,x=1,\,t>0$$

---

There is a lot of information here and I have always struggled with change of variable so I just want suggestions as to what a first step would be.

Comment: In the first equation, the last term has $v$ both at numerator and denominator. This might be an issue. It's not clear what do you need help with. You want to get to the expression with $u$? Or do you need help going further?

Comment: I made a typo, thank you for that. I just don't know how to perform the change of variable method to transform the problem into the desired result. Yes you're right the expression with $u$. What would be the first move? @Andrei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that our OP intended to write

$\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial v^2}{\partial x^2} + \left ( \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \right )^2 \tag 0$

as the first equation in his/her post.

I walk through the steps of the transformation like this:

with

$v = \ln u, \tag 1$

we have

$u = e^v; \tag 2$

$u_t = v_t e^v, \tag 3$

$u_x = v_x e^v, \tag 4$

$u_{xx} = v_{xx} e^v + v_x v_x e^v = v_{xx}e^v + v_x^2 e_v; \tag 5$

then if

$v_t = v_{xx} + v_x^2, \tag 6$

we find

$v_t e^v = v_{xx}e^v + v_x^2 e^v; \tag 7$

now *via* (3) and (5) this may be written

$u_t = u_{xx}. \tag 8$

These steps may in fact be readily reversed; if we start with (8) and assume (1), (0) emerges as a necessary consequence.

Comment: Yes I corrected that typo. okay so rearrange for u, I don't see how lines $(3)$ and $(4)$ come next. How did differentiating $u = e^v$ w.r.t $t$ give a $v_t$ term?

Comment: @MRT:  if $u = e^v$, then $u_t = v_t e^v$ *via* the chain rule for the composition of functions:  if $z = f(y(x))$, then $dz/dx = df/dy(y(x)) dy/dx(x)$; this is very well-known elementary calculus.  Does this help?  Feel free to get back to me with further questions.  Cheers!

Comment: Oh yes $$\Large \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t}\times\frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} v} = v_t\times\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} v}\left(e^v\right) = v_te^v$$ That makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: @MRT:  you got it!